# How can I send email to users from array in php?

Tags: php

Look. This is my code for sending emails for users from my DB, which are input in ne array. 
Can you help me in that situation?

> ```
>   <?php
> $servername = "localhost";
> $username = "user";
> $password = "pass";
> $dbname = "dbname";
> $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
> if ($conn->connect_error) {
>     die("Conexiune esuata: " . $conn->connect_error);
> }    
> $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select email from mst_user");
>     $recipients = array();
>     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
>         $recipients[] = $row['email'];        
>     }
> print_r($recipients);
> $to = implode(" ", $recipients);   
>     $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST["subject"]);
>     $body = $_POST["mesaj"];
>     $headers = "De la profesor@site.ro" ;
>     mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
> $conn->close();
>   ?>
> ```

Comment: You should include solutions you've tried in your question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

`implode` on `,` instead, i.e.:

```
$to = implode(",", $recipients);
```

Comment: My vector look like, and the email do not send to this user's emails.